# C*-algebraic intrinsic definition for compactness of an operator?

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, compact-operators

Some properties of operators (normal, self adjoint, hermitian) have intrinsic definitions for any element of a $C^*$-algebra. Is there such definition for compact operators?

Equivalently:

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $a \in \mathcal{A}$. Suppose that there's a representation of $\mathcal{A}$ in which $a$ is compact. Does it follow that in every irreducible representation of $\mathcal{A}$, $a$ will be compact?

Comment: My intuition says that you cannot guarantee that every representation of $a$ will be compact. Take direct sums (or integrals) of representations of $a$ which are compact. I could be mistaken though. What you might want to say is: is every *irreducible* representation of $a$ compact?

Comment: Let $\pi$ be a representation of $A$ for which $\pi(a)\neq0$ is compact. Then $x\mapsto \pi(x)\oplus\pi(x)\oplus\cdots$ is another representation of $A$ where the image of $a$ is no longer compact, as every point in the spectrum of $a$ has now infinite multiplicity.

Comment: @Phoenix87 Thanks. I see now why it makes much more sense to ask about irreducible representations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is possible that an element is mapped to a compact in one irreducible representation and to a non-compact in another.

For instance, let $I_n\in M_n(\mathbb C)$, $I\in B(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$ be the respectives identities. Let $\mathcal A=M_n(\mathbb C)\oplus B(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$ and $a=I_n\oplus I$. Then the irreducible representation 
$$
\pi_1:(x,y)\longmapsto x
$$
maps $a$ to a compact, while the irreducible representation 
$$
\pi_2:(x,y)\longmapsto y
$$
maps $a$ to a non-compact.

Comment: Good stuff! Your answers are always very enlightening $+1$

Comment: Glad to hear that! I have edited slightly because it is enough to take $a$ to be the identity, no need for more complicated operators.

Comment: That's definitely a better answer. It's interesting to me that representations don't preserve compactness (or non-compactness) though I suppose your example shows they shouldn't. I guess you could even go one further and show that even if you require the Hilbert spaces to be infinite dimensional (to avoid trivialities) it needn't work by letting $\pi_1:(x,y)\mapsto x\oplus 0$.

Comment: But that $\pi_1$ wouldn't be irreducible. Note that C$^*$-algebras such that all irreps map all elements to a compact have a name: they are called CCR or liminary/liminal and were well-studied in the very early years of the theory. GCR or postliminary/postliminal are those C$^*$-algebras such that their image under any  irrep contains the compacts.

Comment: Oh I forgot about the irreducibility condition altogether. I never got around to reading the latter parts of Dixmier so I never actually found out what liminal C$^*$-algebras were. It's a lot less daunting than I would have guessed.